# Replace whitelisted substrings which are surrounded by specified characters with a corresponding value in user-supplied text

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, whitelist

I'm trying to use `preg_replace()` to search for a string but only replace a portion of the string, rather than the entire string, in a dynamic fashion.

For example, I am able to find the strings `od`, `:od`, `od:`, `#od`, and `od`  with my code below. I want to replace only the `od` portion with the word `odometer` and leave the colon, hashtag, and white spaces untouched. However, the way that my current `preg_replace()` is written would replace the colons and the hashtag in addition to the letters themselves. Any creative solutions to replace the characters only but preserve the surrounding symbols?

```
if(isset($_POST["text"]))
{
    $original = $_POST["text"];
    $abbreviation= array();
    $abbreviation[0] = 'od';
    $abbreviation[1] = 'rn';        
    $abbreviation[2] = 'ph';
    $abbreviation[3] = 'real';  
    $translated= array();
    $translated[0] ='odometer';
    $translated[1] ='run';
    $translated[2] ='pinhole';
    $translated[3] ='fake';

function add_regex_finders($str){
    return "/[\s:\#]" . $str . "[\s:]/i";
}

$original_parsed = array_map('add_regex_finders',$original);
preg_replace($original_parsed,$translated,$original);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add capture groups around the characters before and after the matched abbreviation, and then add the group references to the replacement string:

```
function add_regex_finders($str){
    return "/([\s:\#])" . $str . "([\s:])/i";
}

$abbrevs_parsed = array_map('add_regex_finders', $abbreviation);
$translt_parsed = array_map(function ($v) { return '$1' . $v . '$2'; }, $translated);
echo preg_replace($abbrevs_parsed, $translt_parsed, $original);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/TDGbJ)

Note you had a typo in your code, passing `$original` to the call to `add_regex_finders` when it should be `$abbreviation`.

Answer (score 0):

By leveraging a lookup/mapping array, you can perform a single scan of the input string with `preg_replace_callback()`.

If I knew your application a little better, I might suggest merely wrapping your needles in word boundary markers (`\b`).  As it stands, you can simply match the leading whitelisted characters, then forget them with `\K`, then match one of the whitelisted words, then look ahead for the trailing whitelisted characters -- this will ensure that only the word itself is replaced.

In the callback, replace the found word with its mapped value.

Code: [(Demo)](https://3v4l.org/C2LYn)

```
$original = 'some od or perhaps really a #ph in this :rn:';
$abbr = ['od', 'rn', 'ph', 'real'];  
$tran = ['odometer', 'run', 'pinhole', 'fake'];
$map = array_combine($abbr, $tran);

echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/[\s:#]\K(?:' . implode('|', $abbr) . ')(?=[\s:])/i',
         fn($m) => $map[$m[0]] ?? $m[0],
         $original 
     );
// some odometer or perhaps really a #pinhole in this :run:
```